# How to allow users to add playlists to the single YT account?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api, google-api

I would like to know, whether it is possible to allow users to use "transparent" YT account in order to create playlists and add songs to them.

What I want to achieve is:

1. User creates playlist through my service
2. The playlist is transparently (without user's knowledge, and without the need of user having YT account) added to the ROOT account of the service.
3. The database of the service stores information about playlists created by the user.

The documentation for Service Account sounds like it would do the trick, however it doesn't support YT, am I right? If so, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a different tool to do it. Your users won't be able to create playlists, but they will be able to upload into their account and those videos will be added to your playlist for moderation. The ones you approved will go into intended playlist.

[YouTube Direct Lite.](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/)